# find sub folders which contain images

Tags: python, optimization, python-os

What is the most efficent way to get path of subfolders which contain files. For example, if this is my input structure.

```
inputFolder    
│
└───subFolder1
│   │
│   └───subfolder11
│       │   file1.jpg
│       │   file2.jpg
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
    │   file021.jpg
    │   file022.jpg
```

If I pass `getFolders(inputPath)`, 
it should return the output as a list of folders containig images `['inputFolder/subFolder1/subFolder11','inputFolder/folder2']`

Currently I'm making use of my library [TreeHandler](https://github.com/Sreekiranar/treeHandler.git), which is just a wrapper of `os.walk` to get all the files.

```
import os
from treeHandler import treeHandler
th=treeHandler()
tempImageList=th.getFiles(path,['jpg'])
### basically tempImageList will be list of path of all files with '.jpg' extension

### now is the filtering part,the line which requires optimisation.
subFolderList=list(set(list(map(lambda x:os.path.join(*x.split('/')[:-1]),tempImageList))))
```

I think it can be done more efficiently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Splitting all the parts of a path and re-joining them seems to reduce efficiency.
- Finding the index of the last instance of '/' and slicing works much faster.

  ```
  def remove_tail(path):
      index = path.rfind('/') # returns index of last appearance of '/' or -1 if not present
      return (path[:index] if index != -1  else '.') # return . for parent directory
  .
  .
  .
  subFolderList = list(set([remove_tail(path) for path in tempImageList]))
  ```
- Verified on AWA2 dataset folders (50 folders and 37,322 images).
- Observed about 3 times faster result.
- Readability enhanced using the list comprehension.
- Handled case where the parent directory has images (which would result in an error with the existing implementation)

Adding the code used for verification

```
import os
from treeHandler import treeHandler
import time

def remove_tail(path):
    index = path.rfind('/')
    return (path[:index] if index != -1  else '.')

th=treeHandler()
tempImageList= th.getFiles('JPEGImages',['jpg'])
tempImageList = tempImageList
### basically tempImageList will be list of path of all files with '.jpg' extension

### now is the filtering part,the line which requires optimisation.
print(len(tempImageList))
start = time.time()
originalSubFolderList=list(set(list(map(lambda x:os.path.join(*x.split('/')[:-1]),tempImageList))))
print("Current method takes", time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
newSubFolderList = list(set([remove_tail(path) for path in tempImageList]))
print("New method takes", time.time() - start)

print("Is outputs matching: ", originalSubFolderList == newSubFolderList)
```

Comment: makes a lot of sense. Thanks :D

Comment: Optimized the code.
Avoided extra conversion of list to list.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob

original_path = './inputFolder/'

def get_subfolders(path):
    return [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]

def get_files_in_subfolder(subfolder, extension):
    return glob.glob(subfolder + '/*' + extension)

files = []
subfolders = [original_path] + get_subfolders(original_path)
while len(subfolders) > 0:
    new_subfolder = subfolders.pop()
    print(new_subfolder)
    subfolders += get_subfolders(new_subfolder)
    files += get_files_in_subfolder(new_subfolder, '.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(input_folder) if f.is_dir() and any(fname.endswith(tuple(['.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg'])) for fname in os.listdir(f.path))]
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).